# Merged Table Headers in Haml

Tags: html, haml

I am trying to accomplish this in haml:[image]

How do I adjust the following to have merged cell headers to accomplish the same as the excel picture:

```
%table
  %tbody
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th Sunday      
      %th Monday
      %th Tuesday
      %th Wednesday
      %th Thursday
      %th Friday
      %th Saturday
    %tr
      %th 1
      %th 2
      %th 3
      %th 4
      %th 5
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you want the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes. [Here's a demo.](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/rtdfq)

```
%table
  %tbody
    %tr
      %th{:rowspan => 2} Name 
      %th{:colspan => 5} Sunday
      %th{:colspan => 5} Monday
      %th{:colspan => 5} Tuesday
      %th{:colspan => 5} Wednesday
      %th{:colspan => 5} Thursday
      %th{:colspan => 5} Friday
      %th{:colspan => 5} Saturday
    %tr
      - 7.times do
        %th 1
        %th 2
        %th 3
        %th 4
        %th 5
```

Comment: extremely well done, and it was a pleasure to be able to watch your edits, to help me learn your train of thought.   Converted to Haml tonight, and you are making me smile as it comes to fruition!

Comment: the example is so clean and elegant. Just loved it